# What is the thing called RICO?

Tags: united-states

I'm not a law junkie, but I keep hearing this term, RICO, over and over again in different American TV shows (like Better Call Saul, for instance). So could you please explain to me what it is in simple terms (but in a detailed enough manner still)?

Comment: It refers to the Racketeer Influenced and Corrupt Organizations Act of 1970.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racketeer_Influenced_and_Corrupt_Organizations_Act is a start and might help you form a more specific question.

Answer (score 7):

I can do it simple, but [the Popehat can lawsplain it better](https://www.popehat.com/2016/06/14/lawsplainer-its-not-rico-dammit/). The crucial part is:

> It's never RICO!
>
> I mean, not literally never. But I can say with a very high level of confidence that if you're asking me, it's not RICO.

Ok, now, what is Rico? Well, it's short for the [Racketeer Influenced and Corrupt Organizations Act](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-96), and to use it you need to show a lot of stuff as [the RICO jury instructions](https://www.ce9.uscourts.gov/jury-instructions/node/134) show. By the way, that is you need to prove **all these points** list:

> To recover under § 1962(c), a plaintiff must prove (1) conduct, (2) of an enterprise, (3) through a pattern, (4) of racketeering activity (known as "predicate acts"), (5) causing injury to the plaintiff's "business or property" by the conduct constituting the violation.

Judges **hate** RICO. Some even have pre-written orders to demand whoever brings up RICO to show why they believe it is RICO - and [Popehat can show you such a model order.](https://www.popehat.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Rico-Order.pdf)

Comment: I once looked up "racketeering" in the dictionary and got "engaging in a racket". When I looked up "racket", I got "an instance of racketeering".

Comment: Actually, sometimes it is RICO. I've brought civil RICO actions several times on behalf of clients and I've seen some high profile uses of it against the marijuana industry. The joy of RICO is that it converts a criminal offense (which a RICO violation also is) into a civil action that can be privately enforced (which isn't otherwise true of most criminal violations), usually with significant statutory punitive damages and a low threshold for conspiracy liability. The civil actions are usually white collar crime oriented and rarely involve stereotypical organized crime.

Comment: @ohwilleke yes, it *can* be RICO, but the bar to make it such is high.

Comment: @Trish Usually easier than civil conspiracy.

Comment: What qualifies as "racketeering activity"? As @Accumulation pointed out, dictionaries are no help

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev The full list is at 18 USC § 1961(1). https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1961